# Perl Hash of different types of value

Tags: perl, hash

I have an hash. I need to access the array that is in value of Key1. It's actually an array of further hashes.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'student_name' => 'abc',
          'gender'       => 'male',
          'parent_name'  => {
                              'mothe'  => 'jane',
                              'father' => 'victor'
                            },
          'contact'      => [
                              {
                                'phone'   => '12345',
                                'address' => 'home ref'
                              },
                            ]
};
```

I tried to extract `$contact` data like below:

```
my $contact = $hash_name->{"contact"}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Not a hash reference;
```

Comment: Could you please show us your hash structure (instead of explaining it theoretically). Also paste your code what you have tried so far and what result your getting. For more info please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: $VAR1 = [
          {
            'student_name' => 'abc',
            'gender' => 'male',
            'parent_name' => {
                            'mothe' => 'jane',
                           'father' => 'victor'
                          },
            'contact' => [
                           {
                             'phone' => '12345',
                             'address' => 'home ref'
                           },
                           ]

My latest trial is
my $contact = $hash_name->{"contact"}

Error:
Not a hash reference;

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Yes I went through the link which you mentioned but it didn't work.
My hash isnt only of arrays or only of hashes. It's a hash of array and hashes.

Comment: What is `$hash_name`? You've only defined `%hash`. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the difference between a hash and a hashref.

Hashes are initialized and accessed like this:

```perl
my %hash = ( foo => 123 );
print $hash{'foo'}, "\n";
```

Hashrefs are like this; you use the `->` operator to access values:

```perl
my $href = { foo => 123 };
print $href->{'foo'}, "\n";
```

In a nested data structure, the nested items can only be scalars, so not hashes or arrays. Hashrefs and arrayrefs are types of scalars though.

The "outermost" level of the nested structure can still be a hash or array though, and that's the situation you seem to be in.

```perl
my $contact             = $hash_name{'contact'};
my $first_contact       = $hash_name{'contact'}->[0];
my $first_contact_phone = $hash_name{'contact'}->[0]->{'phone'};
```

Perl allows a shorthand when drilling deep into a nested data structure. After the first level, `->` can be omitted.

```perl
my $contact             = $hash_name{'contact'};
my $first_contact       = $hash_name{'contact'}[0];
my $first_contact_phone = $hash_name{'contact'}[0]{'phone'};
```